# HowTo deal with cryptic hidden values for ASP.net? (__VIEWSTATE)

Tags: asp.net, python, parsing, viewstate

I was trying to figure out how to deal with the cryptic "__VIEWSTATE" & Cie when you are trying to request (POST) a page with Python. It is the main source of a lot of problems in my scripts ... and I realize, when I was looking for answers / solutions, that you don't have that much of solutions (almost 0 !).

**In this topic:**
[Unable to load ASP.NET page using Python urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380638/unable-to-load-asp-net-page-using-python-urllib2)
You can see that I am giving my solution with consist in parsing the value of the cryptic fields every time you load the page ... That works, but that's quite stupid actually :-)

```
    for result in the_page.findAll('input', attrs={'name' : '__VIEWSTATE'}):
        view_state =  result['value']

    for result_1 in the_page.findAll('input', attrs={'name' : '__EVENTVALIDATION'}):
        event_validation =  result_1['value']

    for result_2 in the_page.findAll('input', attrs={'name' : '__PREVIOUSPAGE'}):
        previous_page =  result_2['value']

    for result in the_page.findAll('input', attrs={'name' : '__EVENTTARGET'}):
        event_target =  result['value']
```

And after :

```
    url = 'http://bandscore.ielts.org/search.aspx'
    values = {
                            '__EVENTTARGET' : 'gdvSearchResults',
                            '__EVENTARGUMENT' : page,
                        '__VIEWSTATE' : view_state,
                        '__PREVIOUSPAGE' : previous_page,
                        '__EVENTVALIDATION' : event_validation,
                        'DropDownList1'  : Country,
                        #'txtSearchInstitution'  : '',
                        #'hdnSearchText'  : '',
                        #'rdoFilter': '%25',
    }
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5 (Solaris 10) Gecko'
    headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    thePage = response.read()
    the_page = soup(thePage)
```

So here few more links with good explanations / some are proposing solutions:

[What does the __VIEWSTATE hold?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350216/what-does-the-viewstate-hold)

http://aspalliance.com/articleViewer.aspx?aId=135&pId=

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.losformatter.aspx

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

[Mechanize does not see some hidden form inputs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338214/mechanize-does-not-see-some-hidden-form-inputs)

[Unable to load ASP.NET page using Python urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380638/unable-to-load-asp-net-page-using-python-urllib2)

I realize that a lot of people are trying to find a good way to deal with that, so let's try to find a good solution, all together ;-)

**EDIT1**: Found that too, might be interesting http://code.google.com/p/peekviewstate/source/browse/trunk/src/peekviewstate_example.py

(Sorry is this post in not perfect / full of good info ... I'm quite a n00b but I try hard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to deal with it? Just think of `__VIEWSTATE` as opaque data sent to you by the server. It contains some specific data for given page and state of it's objects, and I don't really recommend you to modify it.

If you want to emulate using browser for some ASP.NET application, you need to include those ones in `POST` request, so the server can reconstruct page's state.

What are exact problem it is causing? I think that your solution is pretty straightforward.

Btw, just on a side note - lot of ASP.NET application contains public API, which can be used instead of trying to parse it's pages.